# The subsystem and the components of the system in software engineering

Tags: architecture, components, system

How can i easily distinguish between the subsystem and the components of the system in software engineering ?

Give a detailed definition for each of them..

And to make it more clear to me, lets consider the system is a StackOverflow site, what are its components and the subsystems?

Comment: As a rule of thumb a component is something don't have a meaning/purpose outside the system. A subsystem is something can "live" by itself (even if build for that specific system) but can be abstracted as a black box from the system view point

Comment: Thank you alot !! It becomes clear now .. Please add it as an answer and give me examples .. I have an example but i don't know if it correct or not .. For example in StackOverflow the replaying technique is a subsystem but the delete question we consider it as a component because it doesnt have a meaning outside the system .. Am i right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was cautious to answer this question in part because we have can many definitions depending on the context.

For example you can search for the definitions of system and component in the *UML* literature and find it's different from a Operational Systems book.

That said those are my humble definitions of Components and Subsystems. I'm not claiming that's the utterly right one.

It's just a way I found to organize thing in my head when projecting applications.

Let's first define **"The System"**. Note I call "The" and not "a" system. Because here The System is our context our world.

The system is the project we work on. You mission, as a software engineer / architect / developer, is to bring it to life, maintain it and make it to thrive.

I don't have a definition to "a system" simple because different projects have different contexts.

Even similar projects on different shops got slight different languages due to internal culture.

And IMHO definitions are language dependent and language is culture dependent and culture evolves from a context.

But I digress. In resume you definitions depends on your context.

In DDD for example it's necessary to define an [UbiquitousLanguage](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html)
to make sure everyone is in the same page.

Let's call "blue prints" as the diagrams you use to abstract your project not matter if it's in *UML*, *Bizagi* etc.

A generic definition for **subsystem** can be:

From The System point of view it's a black-box on your top blue prints. In general subsystems got a blue print itself and from it's point of view it's The System.

Subsystem can live by itself and have a well defined purpose and meaning on the system.

Examples:

They a are a kitchen, a bedroom, a basement of a house.

For SO you can say there's a punctuation subsystem, responsible to manage how users earn and lost points.

Note each instance of SE site can have such subsystem and even they can communicate to keep track of your points in many SE sites.

Other example can be the persistence subsystem used to persist and fetch the relevant data.

A generic definition for **component** can be:

They rarely are present on The System Blue Prints and rarely got a blue print themselves.

In general a component don't have a meaning outside the system. They can be used by systems and subsystems but it's purpose is generic.

In a house they are the walls and furniture. A chair in middle of nowhere sounds wrong, the chairs in a meeting room have a use but are not a subsystem.
For SO a component can be a online text editor used to write/edit answers and questions.

It's worth to mention **Third Party Components**:

They can be systems by itself, even very complex ones like a DBMS or *jQuery* *JavaScript* library.

In general it's a error to drawn them in any blue print. They can be used worldwide and be excellent tools but they are black boxes with generic purpose.
For SO they can be the SQL DBMS and *JavaScript* libraries

Summarizing:

- A subsystem can exist without its parent system.
- A component cannot be used alone and must be part of a system to exist.

  To take an analogy :
- A car is a sub-system of travel infrastructure.
- A wheel is a component of the car.

As I said it's just IMHO.